# Select all child nodes in treeView control using C#

Tags: c#, telerik

I try to select all child nodes if the parent node is selected. I'm using a radTreeView from Telerik WinControls. I tried to use the `radTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged()` and got this code:

```
private void machinesTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < machinesTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count; w++)
    {
        machinesTreeView.SelectedNode = machinesTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes[w];
    }
}
```

I debugged it because its just selecting the first one. And then I'd seen that it's logical that it just selects the first one. Because if the code executes

`machinesTreeView.SelectedNode = machinesTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes[w];`

it selects a new one so the `SelectedNodeChanged` event is fired again and then the for loop is unnecessary because there aren't any child nodes on a child node.

So my question is if there is another (maybe better) way to do that?

Suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have a bug in your handler.
If you want to select all subnodes try this:

```
    private void machinesTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < machinesTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count; w++)
        {
            machinesTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes[w].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Do not forget to enable multiselect feature:

```
machinesTreeView.MultiSelect = true;
```

Comment: There is no `.MultiSelect` property for a treeView. Anything else?

Comment: Yes, there is: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/p_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radtreeview_multiselect.html